Cannot see custom modifier?
Directly from the docs, I have:
    <InputText v-model.capitalize="model" />

And:
const [model, modifiers] = defineModel();

console.log(modifiers); // { capitalize: true }

Yet the modifier is not logged, why?

Well, what is logged? and please provide a reproducible example. It works fine in Vue Playground
